# Delphi Chromium Embedded. How to change URL

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I am using Delphi Chromium Embedded (DCEF . vers. 1) in my application. In response to a particular event I should want to change URL of web page displayed by browser. 
I load initial URL by instruction:

```
crm.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(initURL);
```

and it's all ok, page at initURL is correctly displayed.
But when I change to newURL by:

```
crm.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(newURL);
```

browser still remains on old URL, doesn't change.

I have added instruction

```
crm.Browser.ReloadIgnoreCache;
```

after, but nothing changes, page is reloaded, but is still the same.

What's wrong ?

Comment: Should work with crm.Browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(initURL) but try with crm.Load(newUrl);